# ZFS pool broken after upgrading to 14.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, zfs

Well, I have been putting off upgrading to 14.04 for fear that I would break something.  Actually for fear that it would break zfs (or I would break it).   I am bascially slightly better than novice at linux.

Spent the last couple of hours trying to get the pool back.  Now I am at the stage where I don't think I have a complete failure, but I am worried that I may break it.  So if could help me not break it, and recover it,  I would be thankful.

My zfs is file storage and not boot.
It was working fine for a year and was working perfectly before the upgrade (scrub and everything was fine).  I was confident that the upgrade would work (or at least I could fix it) because I had upgraded once in the past, the pool went missing, but I was able to get it back.

I have reinstalled zfs, zfs utilities, and some dependencies (after searching this forum)

I think what happened is 14.04 deleted some config file, or specified disk names differntly, but I could be wrong.  When I set the pool up originally, I was using specific device Ids as I recall (because I did not want to break things if they got reassigned at boot)

So see if this helps.

I can confirm that old mountpoint folders  are there but empty.

```
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
```

pool: naspool1
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing 
    or invalid.  There are insufficient replicas for the pool to continue
    functioning.
action: Destroy and re-create the pool from
    a backup source.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
  scan: none requested
config:

```
NAME                                           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
naspool1                                       UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
  raidz1-0                                     UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
    scsi-SATA_WDC_WD1001FALS-_WD-WMATV0990825  UNAVAIL      0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_WDC_WD1001FALS-_WD-WMATV2995365  UNAVAIL      0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_WDC_WD10EARS-00_WD-WMAV51894349  UNAVAIL      0     0     0


___@ourserver:~$ sudo zpool import naspool1
cannot import 'naspool1': a pool with that name is already created/imported,
and no additional pools with that name were found


___@ourserver:~$ sudo zfs list
 no datasets available
```

What other output can I post to help?  I'm thinking the update deleted some zfs config files.  It seems like the pool exists and certainly 3 perfectly working disks did not fail at once.  I am worried that I may break something without a little bit of guideance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that after the upgrade zfs thinks that this is a different server. You should be able to fix it by simply exporting and then importing the pool.

```
sudo zpool export naspool1
sudo zpool import naspool1
```

Most likely the import will complain that the "pool may be in use by another system, use -f to import it anyway". Use -f to do the import:

```
sudo zpool import naspool1 -f
```